# WPF change tab header color

Tags: wpf

I am trying to set the tab color of the header when the tab is selected. I work with Mah:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuLevel2" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="mah:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="20" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="SteelBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <!-- Sould do the work -->
                <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="SteelBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The text of the header is unfortunately still the one from the theme color. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the [Controls.TabControl.xaml](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.TabControl.xaml) of MahApps.Metro. Most of the design lies in a template. As you can see in line 227 and 274, the `Foreground` is not bound to any property like done with other properties like `Underline` or `HeaderFontSize`.

This means you can't style these properties explicit without creating a whole new template. Since dynamic resources are used as color a solution is to override the used resources. Here is a workaround to change the colors for a tab item like required:

```
<TabItem Header="TabItem1">
    <TabItem.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush" Color="SteelBlue"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightBrush" Color="SteelBlue"/>
    </TabItem.Resources>
</TabItem>
```